# MySQL how to count distinct values added per day?

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to figure a command to count the number of distinct values added each day.

It'd basically take the `COUNT(DISTINCT(username))` for day is less than `x days - COUNT(DISTINCT(username))` where day is less than `x-1` day.

**Example Data:**

```
username | FK  | ipNum      | timestamp
boy      | 404 | 219395     | 2013-01-06 22:23:56
boy      | 404 | 467719     | 2013-01-10 22:23:41
boy1     | 404 | 4718869    | 2013-01-11 22:23:42
boy      | 404 | 16777224   | 2013-01-12 22:23:56
boy2     | 404 | 1292435475 | 2013-01-13 22:23:25
boy3     | 404 | 1526990605 | 2013-01-14 22:23:57
boy4     | 404 | 1594313225 | 2013-01-15 22:23:40
boy      | 404 | 1610613001 | 2013-01-16 22:23:23
boy4     | 404 | 1628635192 | 2013-01-17 22:23:55
boy3     | 404 | 2130706433 | 2013-01-25 21:29:38
boy2     | 407 | 2130706433 | 2013-01-25 21:31:59
boy3     | 407 | 2130706433 | 2013-01-26 21:32:22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp), COUNT(DISTINCT username)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY 1;
```

(I don't understand your `x` comments.  Perhaps you need to add a `WHERE` clause to limit the date range.)